# How to dynamically set a value for an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

```
<script>' +

        'var doughnutData = [' +
        '{' +
        ' value: percentage,' +
//not work with this variable but with a number like 50 it work
        ' color:"#68dff0"' +``
        '},' +
        '{' +
        'value : remain,' +
//not work with this variable but with a number like 50 it work
        'color : "#444c57"' +
        '}' +
        ' ];' +
        'var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("serverstatus0' + i + '").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(x);' +
        ' </script>' +
```

I have this script for the creation of a chart and i want to dynamically assign value for the creation of it but if i only assign my 'percentage' variable to the value: . 
How i can do for reaching my purpose?

Comment: Why is your code structured like this?

Comment: When you say "dynamically assign value for the creation of it" what do you mean? What do you want to set?

Comment: Why are you building the script this way? Is this being built on the server? There are better ways of doing this.

Comment: It looks like you are wondering how to pass arguments to the object constructor with values that can be placed into the object. Is that right?

Comment: Take a good look at JS  [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Use a transpiler if your targeted environments don't support them.

Comment: ...in any case, you're already handling this with the `i` variable, so if `percentage` is a variable, why wouldn't you do the same thing there?

Comment: Template literal: https://jsfiddle.net/sy56x91b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is percentage a variable?

If so it would be:

' +

```
    'var doughnutData = [' +
    '{' +
    ' value: ' + percentage + ',' +
    ' color:"#68dff0"' +``
    '},' +
    '{' +
    'value : '+ remain + ',' +
    'color : "#444c57"' +
    '}' +
    ' ];' +
    'var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("serverstatus0' + i + '").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(x);' +
    ' </script>' +
```

See how I changed the remain and percentage text to not be in the quotes?

Comment: thanks i had already tried this method yesterday but it won't work, i try again now and ti works

Comment: No problem, please put as best answer if it helped! Thanks!